# 404 error on admin/customer_group/save

Tags: admin, customer-group, 404-page

I need help troubleshooting my issue. I don't know what to look for. Magento 1.9.1.0. For what it's worth, this issue is probably related to the extension **Webtex_CustomerGroupsPrice**.

When I go to **Customers > Customer Groups** then I click **Add New Customer Group**, the page `/index.php/admin/customer_group/new/key/.../` displays.

Then I type in a group name and hit **Save**. The next page is:
`/index.php/admin/customer_group/save/key/.../?code=stuff&tax_class=3`

and I get a **404 Not Found** error from the frontend theme.

I have tried disabling the extension **Webtex_CustomerGroupsPrice** which does not change the symptom. I am just beginning to learn how the database works so if it's as simple as fixing a row in a table I can do that.

A rewrite exists in
`app/code/local/Webtex/CustomerGroupsPrice/etc/config.xml:`

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <rewrite>
            <customergroupsprice_customer_group>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/admin/customer_group/save/#]]></from>
                <to>/customergroupsprice/group/save/</to>
```

Is this the issue? Why isn't that rewrite taking place? I have no idea what to do. Where should I be looking to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Are you by chance using a restricted admin account, i.e. a user that doesn't have a role with "all permissions"?

Comment: No, I'm using the main admin account. Thank you though.

Comment: first of all, a 404 will never be report in your log. Anyway the problem is about a rewrite done by a custom module. You have to check the config.xml of any possible rewriting module

Comment: `.../index.php/admin/admin/...` Double admin? It's look like wrong.

Comment: DenisSpalenza and AntoninoBonumore, Thank you for the feedback. I have provided more info. I will check into config.xml soon.

Comment: @AntoninoBonumore I have updated the question with more details axout config.xml. (about, not axout. sorry)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to install this extension and everything looks fine in same magento version.Try to clean your cache, logout and login again: could be a simple issue regarding xml updates (flush all xmls).

Comment: Interesting. Flushing the cache fixes the issue when the extension is deactivated (set false in app/etc/modules). When the extension is on, flushing the cache, even rm -r var/cache/* doesn't fix the issue. I may just continue without the extension.

Answer (score 2):

same problem after buy Webtex_CustomerGroupsPrice and install on 1.9.2.1

After change config xml from

```
<rewrite>
      <customergroupsprice_customer_group>
    <from><![CDATA[#^/admin/customer_group/save/#]]></from>
    <to>/customergroupsprice/group/save/</to>
      </customergroupsprice_customer_group>
    </rewrite>
```

to

```
<rewrite>
      <customergroupsprice_customer_group>
    <from><![CDATA[#^/customer_group/save/#]]></from>
    <to>/customergroupsprice/group/save/</to>
      </customergroupsprice_customer_group>
    </rewrite>
```

it works!

btw: Magento > 1.7 have group prices on board ;-)